# Can I know which thread change the global variable's value from core dump file?

Tags: c, multithreading, unix, gdb, coredump

My program is a multi-thread program written in C, and runs on Solaris.

Now, a variable (malloced in heap) is sometimes changed from a valid value to `NULL`, so when accessing it, core dump occurs.

I have tried all the methods I know: using libumem, add logs, code walk-through, and nothing can be found.

So when I analyse the core dump file again, I have a fantastic idea: Can I know which thread change the global variable (including malloced from heap)'s value from core dump file? Anyone can give some clues from core dump file?

Comment: No, not really. You could try to set a memory breakpoint to see when the variable is getting set to NULL?

Comment: why not check for `NULL` before accessing it?

Comment: @NPE: the memory is malloced when receiving a message, after processing the message, the memory will be freed. This isn't a always issue, so I can't set memory breakpoint.

Comment: @SakthiKumar: checking NULL can't find the root cause of this bug.

Comment: @NanXiao checking null can't find your root cause it prevent cause of it.

Comment: It might be worth `valgrind`ing your application, to see if the problem is the result of a memory bug of some sort (there's of course no guarantee that this is the case).

Comment: I would bet for tracepoints http://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Tracepoints.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can I know which thread change the global variable (including malloced from heap)'s value from core dump file?

No.

A core dump records current state of the process memory at crash point, not the history of it. Just as looking at a photo of a spray-painted graffiti on the wall you can't tell who painted it, looking at `NULL` in a core dump will not tell you who put it there.